# Creepy film with tentacle alien attacking crew members in a vessel in space or underwater

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I think it must have been before 1991 the film came out.
I think it was set in space or maybe deep underwater. The vessel had narrow rounded sci-fi corridors. They seemed trapped so definitely a station of sorts.

The alien/creature came from a can (like a baked bean tin without the wrapper).

This creature was like oozy tentacles which were brown and slimy and would reach out and grab the crew members and drag them away. And had grown pretty long.

Comment: You have a nice start here but could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in?

Answer (score 22):

This sounds like [*Leviathan*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097737/plotsummary?ref_=tt_stry_pl) to me a 1989 deep sea mining horror movie.

> Underwater deep-sea miners encounter a Soviet wreck and bring back a dangerous cargo to their base on the ocean floor with horrifying results. The crew of the mining base must fight to survive against a genetic mutation that hunts them down one by one.

***The alien/creature came from a can (like a baked bean tin without the wrapper).***

Not a can but a vodka flask.

> After Williams and Sixpack return from the wreck, the rest of the crew open a safe from The Leviathan that Sixpack took and find several crew records relating to deceased crew members, as well as a video tape from the captain of Leviathan. Among the materials, Sixpack finds a flask of Vodka. There being no alcohol on their underwater base, he hides this for his own use later. Bowman figures out Sixpack had hidden away the Vodka and persuades him to share it.

[image: Flask that contains the mutagens]

***This creature was like oozy tentacles which were brown and slimy and would reach out and grab the crew members and drag them away. And had grown pretty long.***

> Despite the bodies being flushed, a piece of Sixpack's mutating leg remains on board and continues to mutate into a lamprey/leech-like creature. This attacks Dejesus in the kitchen. Jones tried to get help, but the creature assimilates Dejesus and begins growing tentacles that randomly attack the crew. Cobb's injuries cause him to mutate as well and he infects Dr. Thompson.

[image: Tentacle head] [image: Tentacle monster attacks]

Comment: Edited in some extra information from the synopsis to match the OPs points and screenshots from the film which appear to match their memory.

Comment: Although they share lots of simularities. Sadly, this isn't it. The monster/creature/alien came from a can. And the tentacles were more brown and slimey (cheap looking too)

Comment: @Xiikie The latter scene in the answer starts around [1h 1m 39s](https://youtu.be/1zMruvOe15E?t=1h1m39s). He does grab some wires that flail and the monster is certainly slimy and cheap looking.

Comment: Is this just The Thing underwater?

Answer (score 9):

It's not a film - but could you possibly be talking about the Red Dwarf episode [Emohawk - Polymorph II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emohawk:_Polymorph_II)?

It's Episode 4 of Series 6. A clip of the "baked beans" scene can be seen here:

Comment: +1 because it's about Ace Rimmer! Every time I see him mentioned in an answer (even if incorrect answer) I feel it deserves an upvote

Comment: Its definately not red dwarf either XD

Comment: “Smoke me a kipper, I’ll be back for breakfast”

Comment: " What a guy ! "

Comment: Would it make any difference if it was hummus?

Answer (score 3):

It could be [*DeepStar Six* (1989)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097179/).

> A group of U.S. Navy engineers, led by Capt. Laidlaw (Taurean Blacque), are building an underwater base when they inadvertently disturb the lair of a gigantic creature. The monster attacks, and the crew, including lovers Collins (Nancy Everhard) and McBride (Greg Evigan), tries to evacuate, but the facility is badly damaged. After the exterior is breached, the increasingly desperate people become separated from one another, and the creature begins to pick them off one by one.

Or alternatively it might be [The Rift](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099701/?ref_=nv_sr_2?ref_=nv_sr_2).

Comment: I've edited in some basic information of the story from the link, could you edit to explain why this is correct and how it matches the OP's description?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like [*Star Crystal*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092006/) (1986) to me.

> Crew members aboard a space ship encounter an alien life form intent on killing them.

The hidden image below shows the monster's tentacles wrapped around Lieutenant Billi Lynn.

> [image: Lieutenant Billi Lynn with monster's tentacles attacking her]

Comment: I've edited in some basic information for why this is correct, could you [edit] to add in how this matches the OP's description? See [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/58193) for some general help.